# HTML: New Line not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, line-breaks

I basically just want to display each entry of local storage on a new line inside a list element.

Here is my JS:

```
if ( counter == 1 ){
var json = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem( localStorage.key( i )))
var textm = 'Entry:'+json.Entry+'\n Exercise: '+json.Exercise+'\n Date:'+json.Date+'\n Start: ' +json.Start+'\n End: '+json.End+'\n Calories: '+json.Calories;
 var ul = document.getElementById("list");
 var li = document.createElement("li");

 li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(textm));
 ul.appendChild(li);


};
```

Very long i know, but this is the output I receive:

[image]

What is the reasoning for this? Do I not use line breaks right? or could it potentially be my CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you are using `<pre>` elements, or the equivalent CSS formatting, browsers treat newline characters as spaces, and condense multiple whitespace characters down to a single space. To have your fields appear on separate lines you need to insert `<br>` line break elements rather than newline characters. (Or use a nested list, or wrap each "line" in a `<p>` element, or whatever. But just using `<br>` elements is simplest.)

Except that because you are setting the text with `.createTextNode()` simply including `"<br>"` in your string would display those characters rather than creating an element. The simplest solution to this is to set the `.innerHTML` of your `<li>` element rather than using `.createTextNode()`:

```
if (counter == 1) {
  var json = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)))
  var textm = 'Entry:' + json.Entry + '<br> Exercise: ' + json.Exercise + '<br> Date:' + json.Date
            + '<br> Start: ' + json.Start + '<br> End: ' + json.End + '<br> Calories: ' + json.Calories;
  var ul = document.getElementById("list");
  var li = document.createElement("li");

  li.innerHTML = textm;
  ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

As an aside, you don't need a semicolon after the closing `}` of an `if` block. Also, assuming the above code is contained in a loop, it would be more efficient to move the line with `var ul = document.getElementById("list");` to before the loop, so that you only have to lookup that element once instead of doing it on every loop iteration.

Comment: You sir are a life saver, well done, this answer was suggested two times before but failed to realize the .createTextNode() problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Update your text concatenation with `<br/>` instead of `\n` like below.

```
var textm = 'Entry:'+json.Entry+'<br/> Exercise: '+json.Exercise+'<br/> Date:'+json.Date+'<br/> Start: ' +json.Start+'<br/> End: '+json.End+'<br/> Calories: '+json.Calories;

li.innerHTML = textm;
```

Comment: this has already been suggested but was deleted, I Get this error when doing this, Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Comment: you need to do innerHTML not appendChild.

Answer (score 0):

In html as [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp) says,for breaking line we must use <br> instead of \n(or any other character).
I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your soultion

You need to create element. you can't pass it as a string

Example : `document.createElement("br");`

```
if ( counter == 1 ){
    var json = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem( localStorage.key( i )))
    var textm = 'Entry:'+json.Entry+document.createElement("br")+' Exercise: '+json.Exercise+'\n Date:'+json.Date+'\n Start: ' +json.Start+'\n End: '+json.End+'\n Calories: '+json.Calories;
     var ul = document.getElementById("list");
     var li = document.createElement("li");

     li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(textm));
     ul.appendChild(li);


    };
```