# “\n\n” not being recognized from Array

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I currently have a `<textarea/>` field that when you press enter it submits and makes a new item on the array. When you press **shift + enter** it creates a new line in the `<textarea/>` input field.

However, when you actually press shift and enter to make a new break and submit it; it does not recognize the break in the line. I have attached images below.

[image: Image of while typing]

[image: Image of after item is added]

As you can see above, its like the array does not recognize there is a break in the input.

**Todobox.jsx:**

```
import React, { createContext } from 'react';
import Item from './Item';
import { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import trash from '../trash_can.png'
import { ElementContext } from '../ElementContext';

export const ItemContext = createContext();

export const ItemContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    const [itemId, setItemId] = useState(1);
    const [itemData, setItemData] = useState(); 
    const [refDict, setRefDict] = useState({});

    const newItemId = (items) =>{
        setItemId(itemId + 1);
        console.log(itemId)
    }

    const newItem = (itemChange, boxid) => {
        newItemId();
        if (!refDict[itemId]) {
          setItems(prev => [...prev, { itemboxid: boxid, itemdata: itemChange, itemid: itemId }]);
          setRefDict((prev) => ({...prev, [itemId]: true}));
        }
        console.log(items);
    };

    const value = {
        items,
        setItems,
        newItem,
        itemId
    };

    return(
        <ItemContext.Provider value={value}>
            {children}
        </ItemContext.Provider>
    )
};

export default function Todobox({ boxtitle, boxid }){
    const { elements, setElements, newTitle } = useContext(ElementContext);
    const { items, setItems, newItem } = useContext(ItemContext);
    const [boxheader, setBoxHeader] = useState('');
    const [itemChange, setItemChange] = useState('');

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setBoxHeader(e.target.value);
    }

    const handleKeydown = (e) => {
        if(e.keyCode == 13 && e.shiftKey == false){
            setElements(elements.map(element => {
                if (element.boxid === boxid) {
                  setBoxHeader(e.target.value)
                  return { ...element, boxtitle: boxheader };
                } else {
                  return element;
                }
              }))
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('Title has been set to: ' + boxheader);
        }
    }

    const handleDelete = (e) => {
        setElements(elements.filter(element => element.boxid !== boxid))
    }

    const handleItemChange = (e) =>{
        setItemChange(e.target.value);
    }

    const handleNewItem = (e) =>{
        if(e.keyCode == 13 && e.shiftKey == false){
            newItem(itemChange, boxid)
            e.preventDefault();
            e.target.value = '';
        }
    }
    
    return(
        <>
        <div className='element-box'>
            <img src={trash} className='element-box-trash' onClick={handleDelete}></img>
            <textarea className='element-title-input' placeholder='Add title...' onChange={handleChange} onKeyDown={handleKeydown} value={boxheader}></textarea>
            {items.map(item => {
                if(item.itemboxid === boxid){
                    return <Item key={item.itemid} itemid={item.itemid} itemdata={item.itemdata}/>;
                } else if(item.itemboxid !== boxid){
                    return null;
                }
            })}
            <textarea 
            className='element-input' 
            type='text' 
            placeholder={`Add item... ${boxid}`}
            onChange={handleItemChange}
            onKeyDown={handleNewItem}
            onClick={() => {console.log(boxid)}}
            />
        </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

**Item.jsx:**

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import { ElementContext } from '../ElementContext';
import { ItemContext } from './Todobox';

export default function Item({ itemid, itemdata }){
    const { setHideModal, modals, setModals } = useContext(ElementContext);

    const handleNewModal = () => {
        setHideModal(false)
        setModals(prev => [...prev, { modalItemId: itemid, modalId: '1', modalData: itemdata }]);
        console.log(modals);
    };

    return(
        <div className='item-container' onClick={handleNewModal}>
            <a className='item-text'>{itemdata}</a>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Item-input css:**

```
.item-text {
  padding: 2px;
  opacity: 1;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

**Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advanced! :)**

Comment: You need to preserve whitespace in your CSS: `white-space: pre-wrap`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML: New Line not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43714101/html-new-line-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

@caTS answered my question in a comment.

I had to add `white-space: pre-wrap` to my CSS.